# "Polynomials" with non-integer exponents

Tags: reference-request, roots

Are there some books or articles regarding "polynomials" with non-integer (real) exponents, i.e., $$f(x)=a_1x^{e_1}+a_2x^{e_2}+\dots+a_nx^{e_n},$$
where $e_1,e_2,\dots$ are any real numbers (and $x$ being also real)?

I am mostly interested in theorems regarding the location of the roots, number of the roots, bounds, etc., of such "polynomials". Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the keyword is *exponential polynomial* because $x^\alpha=e^{\alpha \log x}$.

Try these papers:

- J.F. Ritt, [On the zeros of exponential polynomials](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1929-031-04/S0002-9947-1929-1501506-6/), 
  *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **31** (1929), 680–686.
- C.J. Moreno, [The zeros of exponential polynomials (I)](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CM_1973__26_1_69_0). *Compositio Mathematica*, **26** (1973), 69–78.
- G.J.O. Jameson, [Counting zeros of generalized polynomials: Descartes' rule of signs and Laguerre's extensions](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~jameson/zeros.pdf),  *Math. Gazette* **90**,(2006), 223–234.

Comment: This is a little misleading since the sort of thing pisoir is looking for would be an exponential polynomial in $\log x$, not in $x$. The third bullet point seems to provide "generalized polynomials", so maybe that's the most appropriate name? In [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4675959/terminology-for-polynomials-but-with-arbitrary-exponents?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment9885255_4675959), [kimchi-lover](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/457779/kimchi-lover) suggests the little-attested [signomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signomial) as well.

Answer (score 4):

One term for this is [signomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signomial), where the argument is restricted to the positive reals, to avoid definition problems of things like $x^{\sqrt 2}$ for negative $x$, and so on.  I hope this term is not in widespread use, but the Wikipedia page does refer to a textbook that uses it.